GFS model orography
I'm looking for the model orography of GFS but cannot find it. I tried to download a GRIB file from nomads checking all parameters but it doesn't contain the orography. I need it because I do some hydrological modelling which relies on a much finer spatial resolution and I want do correct GFS´s parameters by a quite straight foreward downscaling method.
Does anyone know where I can find the model orography? The link provided by What is the vertical offset of geopotential height from ellipsoidal height in GFS? does not exist anymore.

I got it. In the inventory of the gfs grib file there is a parameter called geopetenial height (HGT) at the "surface" level. This is supposed to be the model's orography.
However, in the grib file, using QGIS to open it, the parameter is called SFC at the "ground or water surface" level.
